# How to stretch a Card in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a row containing between 1 and 4 cards. I would like the cards to stretch to fill up the whole width of the display, but I cannot figure out which modifier to use.
This my code:

```
Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(contentPadding)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
          # Number of cards can be 1-4
          repeat(2) {
              Card(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
                  Text(text = "Hello")
              }
          }
}
```

Which width-modifier should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a weight modifier in the cards like this:

```
Card(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().weight(1f)) {
    Text(text = "Hello")
}
```

if you need extra space add a spacer after the text.

EDIT full code and imports:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Card
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun CardsFillParentSize() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
        repeat(2) {
            Card(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().weight(1f)) {
                Text(text = "Hello")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot find the weight modifier for Card. It seems only available for Row and Column.

Comment: I've added the imports in my answer. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [weight modifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#weight), wich defines the width of the card according to its weight. (Example : if one has a weight of 3 and one of 1, then the first will be 3 times wider)

This would look like

```
Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(contentPadding)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
          # Number of cards can be 1-4
          repeat(2) {
              Card(modifier = Modifier
                             .fillMaxHeight()
                             .weight(1f)) {
                  Text(text = "Hello")
              }
          }
}`
```